# CSS3 How do i add a hyperlink to <div data-image="#">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

sorry i've tried asking this before and got no good results, so here's trying again.
I have tried many things and still haven't had any good results.

The code is here -> **[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/QyPvcbNm)**

I want to add a hyperlink to the data-images for the ninja slider. I've never encountered data-image before but i can't use img src="#" cause that doesn't work with the javascript if you guys need any more information, let me know. This is driving me insane!

```
  <div id='ninja-slider'>
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                        <div data-image="images/md/1.jpg"> </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <div data-image="images/md/2.jpg"> </div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <div data-image="images/md/3.jpg"></div>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                         <div data-image="images/md/4.jpg"></div>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
```

this is the troublesome part.

Comment: Are you trying to make is so when you click a slide (li) it links to another section or make it so when another section is clicked it links to a certain slide?

Comment: I want it to link to another page in the parent directory called "music.html"

Comment: I would, then, suggest you use `God is good`'s answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use java script to add link

Example:

```
 <div onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com/'" data-image="images/md/1.jpg"> </div>
```

Also you can use css to change the pointer

```
 #ninja-slider ul li div{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: Be aware that this markup will not allow users that navigate with the keyboard to focus or activate the locations.

Answer (score 3):

Simply enclose your `<div>`s within an `<a>` tag.  That way the `<div>`s are technically links.

```html
<div id='ninja-slider'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="images/md/1.jpg">
        <div data-image="images/md/1.jpg"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/md/2.jpg">
        <div data-image="images/md/2.jpg"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/md/3.jpg">
        <div data-image="images/md/3.jpg"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/md/4.jpg">
        <div data-image="images/md/4.jpg"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<div onclick="location.href='http://www.example.com';" />
```

Or use span or a tags instead

```
<style type="text/css">
.myspan {
    display: block;
}
</style>
<a href="#"><span class="myspan">text</span></a>
```